# What is wrong with calculating total charges thru out my program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello my program can count how many customers and tell the customer their price based on the amount of hours but cannot add the total charges to save my life
Here’s my code

```
count = 1
total_charge = 0
total = 0
hours_parked = 0
ask = 1
standardRate = 2.00
FEE = .50
def calculate_charges(x, f, sr, t):
    if x <= 3:
        sr = 2.00
        t = sr
        print(t)
    elif x >= 3 and x <= 24:
        sr = 2.00
        f = (x - 3) * .50
        t = f + sr
        print(t)
    else:
        print("We only allow 24 hours tops. Check the number of hours again!")
        main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)
        
def main(c, y, h, a, t):
    h = int(input("How many hours did the customer park?"))
    calculate_charges(h, FEE, standardRate, total)
    c += 1
    a = int(input("Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)"))
    if a == 1:
        y = t + y
        main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)
    else:
        y = t + y
        c += 1
        print("There was a total of ", c, " customers and a profit of $", y, "for the day!" )
main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)
```

```
How many hours did the customer park?2
2.0
Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)1
How many hours did the customer park?2
2.0
Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)2
There was a total of  3  customers and a profit of $ 0 for the day!
```

Comment: You could probably make your life a bit easier by giving semantic names to your variables.  It's more typing, but it will make for easier debugging when you are looking at the code and the name of the variable describes what it is...

Comment: Understandable but I’m pretty new  just can’t see why it wont add up total charges thruout the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous code did not add up the results of the previous calculation.

```py
count = 0
total_charge = 0
total = 0
hours_parked = 0
ask = 1
standardRate = 2.00
FEE = .50


def calculate_charges(x, f, sr):
    if x <= 3:
        t = sr
        print(t)
    else:
        f = (x - 3) * f
        t = f + sr
        print(t)
    return t


def main(c, y, h, a, t):
    while True:
        h = abs(int(input("How many hours did the customer park?")))
        if h > 24:
            print("We only allow 24 hours tops. Check the number of hours again!")
        else:
            break
    t += calculate_charges(h, FEE, standardRate)
    c += 1
    a = int(input("Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)"))
    if a == 1:
        y = t + y
        main(c, y, h, ask, total)
    else:
        y = t + y
        print("There was a total of ", c, " customers and a profit of $", y, "for the day!")


main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)
```

```
How many hours did the customer park?27
We only allow 24 hours tops. Check the number of hours again!
How many hours did the customer park?6
3.5
Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)1
How many hours did the customer park?28
We only allow 24 hours tops. Check the number of hours again!
How many hours did the customer park?10
5.5
Is there more customers?(Type 1 for YES and 2 for NO.)2
There was a total of  2  customers and a profit of $ 9.0 for the day!
```

Comment: If beast had a picture it’d be u your a beast thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling

```
main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)
```

but `count`, `total_charge`, `hours_parked`, `ask` and `total` are not being updated anywhere.

So you're passing in `total_charge = 0` and that's what the program is returning.

Try passing `c, y, h, a, t` into `main` within your main function. (btw, it might be simpler to do everything in a `while` in the `calculate_charges` function)

Also...
It may be easier for you to figure out what's happening if your variables have meaningful names. After studying CompSci for 4 years in undergrad and now as a graduate student, one important lesson I've learned is that following coding convention will pay off both in the short run and in the long run.

Comment: What do you mean by passing them within my main? Btw thanks for helping

Comment: This:
`if a == 1:
        y = t + y
        main(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)`

Replace `(count, total_charge, hours_parked, ask, total)` with `c, y, h, a, t`